# Not how to create a session timeout in Php, but where?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, timeout

My boss purchased some web-based software (PC Repair Tracker...it's amazing), and put me in charge of installing it on our domain, configuring the database, the pricing, the look and feel (html/css). the ticketing system, etc. It's basically a template that you purchase and fully customize to meet your needs.

Configuring it wasn't too bad, even considering I am still a novice with PHP MySQL, etc. My boss requested I "make it logout after a certain time" because it contains sensitive info, and repairs are tracked by employee to know who to go to when information is needed on a device that's at our store. 
What he means is that I need to write a timeout function.

The problem is not just creating the timeout function, but knowing where to put it? There are probably close to 100 files the website folder, each one of them a .php file (except for css stuff and images). Do I use the intuitive approach and start with login.php?

And how do I know what to call my variables?

The interface begins at the landing page with a login form. I don't think I would want to start at login.php, because they need to at least be logged in.

I installed FirePHP for Firefox and I noticed a function being called: It says:

```
    GET ajaxhelpers.php?func=refreshnotifications
```

It pops up every minute or so. When I find that .php file, it's very short, and says:

```
    if (array_key_exists('func',$_REQUEST)) {
$func = $_REQUEST['func'];
} else {
$func = "";
}
function nothing() {
}
function refreshnotifications() {
require("deps.php");
require_once("common.php");
echo pcrtnotify();
}
switch($func) {

    default:
    nothing();
    break;

    case "refreshnotifications":
    refreshnotifications();
    break;
}
?>
```

I also found a "validate.php" that sends a user to the login page. Could I put a function there?

```
<?php
        include("deps.php");
$validated = false;

//Use $_COOKIE to get the cookie data . same usage as $_POST
if(isset($_COOKIE["username"])&&isset($_COOKIE["password"])) {

$user = $_COOKIE["username"];
$pass = $_COOKIE["password"];

//Begin validation code
if(isset($passwords[$user])) if($passwords[$user]== $pass) $validated = true;
//End validation code
}

if($validated) {
//Ok; don.t need to do anything
} else {
//Make user go to login page

die("<a href=../store/login.php class=\"linkbuttonmedium linkbuttongray radiusall\">please login</a>");


exit;
}
?>
```

Is this a good start? Sorry for the lengthy question. I'm not asking for homework advice or anything. I'm just trying to learn php in a crash course fashion because he's going to want results yesterday. Lol.

It seems like I could put a condition in there that says,

```
    if($validated && idle_time > time_allowed) {
       go to logout.php
    }
```

But then again, I'm a php noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for session_start() and before that line add the following

```
session_set_cookie_params(3600,"/");
```

The number is in seconds. So 3600 represents one hour.

Comment: tried to find that, but I'm seeing no function with that name. I'm on a Linux machine, and I have a copy of the files on my machine, and I did "grep -R "session_start()" with no results

Comment: Did you remember the dot in the end? "grep -R "session_start() ."

Comment: as you can see from my answer, that's pretty much what I changed. Mine was set to 10 hours. So, since you led me in the right direction, I'll leave my answer to show what I did, and accept yours. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I did some more digging, and I discovered a validate2.php, and logout.php file. Well, I already knew logout.php existed, I just looked closer at the code. 
Inside, it contains conditional logic for a variable, $cookiedomain, and it also contained values for when a cookie expired for the user. If I'm saying all of this wrong, forgive me. I'm still learning php. Just trying to apply fundamental logic to all this.

So, what the validate.php file eventually does is check if the boolean $validated is true. If it's true, it continues and give you the ability to refresh. If it is **not** validated, you are presented with a tiny button on the screen that says "Please login". 
1) This was incredibly sloppy and hard to find. 
2) The time was set to 10 hours.

So, for testing purposes, I set the numbers to 20 in validate.php and logout.php, like so (I'm using the new value - 120 - in my code because I changed it since 20 seconds was too short obviously):

**login.php**

```
if(isset($cookiedomain)) {
setcookie("username", $user, time()+120, "/","$cookiedomain");
setcookie("password", $pass, time()+120, "/","$cookiedomain"); 
} else {
setcookie("username", $user, time()+120, "/");
setcookie("password", $pass, time()+120, "/");
}
```

**logout.php**

```
        if(isset($cookiedomain)) {
setcookie("username", $user, time()-120, "/","$cookiedomain");
setcookie("password", $pass, time()-120, "/","$cookiedomain");
} else {
setcookie("username", $user, time()-120, "/");
setcookie("password", $pass, time()-120, "/");
}
```

**validate2.php**

```
        if($validated) {
  //Ok. don't need to do anything
} else {
//Make user go to login page
echo '<script type ="text/javascript">alert("Sorry, ' . $user . ', but you have been logged out due to inactivity.");</script>';

 exit;
}
```

It's still not printing the user name, just a ' ', so I still need to work on that. The ugly button is gone, and it gives the user a nice, obvious notification that they've been logged out. 
I would like to make the button redirect, so now on to working that part out.