# PHP session update at certain time

Tags: php, mysql, session, refresh

I have a php website where I need to unsubscribe a student after one month for example .. for each student I have a "subscribed" value in the mysql database where it can be 0 (unsubscribed) or 1 (subscribed).. I also have a registration date whereby I can know the time after one month for each student.
the question is, how can I unset the "logged in" and the "subscriebd" session at that time?.. how can I log that user out ?..  because even if I update the database and the subscribed becomes 0 instead of 1 .. the session won't refresh on its own and it will remain 1 ..

Thanks

Comment: Do you intend to logout the user after 1 month? If yes, I don't recommend it. The subscribed/unsubscribed part I can understand but login session shouldn't stay that long. I see web-app usually have inactivity logout time at 30 minutes or so? For banking app it's a lot shorter than that, maybe 5-10 minutes of inactivity.

Comment: I meant, if the user remained logged in, for example he doesn't close the browser and just minimizes it (like in mobile phones), then even if the 'subscribed' became zero in the database, it will remain 1 in the session (unless the user refreshes + I have an if statement to check for the time and unset the session).. so what to do to force it to refresh when the time comes?.. should I use AJAX ? or is there a solution within php ..

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427783/not-how-to-create-a-session-timeout-in-php-but-where . The keyword here is "session timeout", I think if you search "PHP session timeout", you'll find more information about it. Basically, the timeout was imposed at the time user login so regardless if the user logout or not, the session will timeout anyway. Some web-app that I use will pop-up a window telling that my session timed-out but some doesn't - but when I refresh the page, it will redirect me to the login page.

Comment: @FanoFN Thanks, I've checked this question before I posted mine, I've went through the comments and the replies, and I felt that it will not do exactly what I am intending to .. but I started to get convinced about the idea of unsetting the session, and leaving the "kicking out" until the user refreshes somehow .. and, I am avoiding JavaScript to keep everything on the server, away from the users manipulation with the code.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use

```
unset($_SESSION['sessionid']);
```

Comment: But if I write an if statement like if(time( )>= $some_time){ //unset the session}; it will not be executed unless the user refreshes the page ..

Comment: @MuhammadSaif _"it will not be executed unless the user refreshes the page"_ - and what is the problem with that? Whatever _next_ action they tried to trigger with that click, will fail then, because they are not logged in any more. If you want this to trigger while they are "on" the page, but without any explicit user interaction - then periodically check the session via an AJAX request or something.

Comment: @CBroe This is what I thought about .. but at the same time, the way you said your comment let me think again on keeping the if statement that checks for the time and unsets the session, until the user refreshes the page .. thanks